# SQL Unique Constraint on two attributes that are 'interchangeable'

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, h2

I have the following table:

```
create table logical_connection (
  id varchar(36) not null,
  device0id varchar(36) not null,
  device1id varchar(36) not null,
  version bigint,
  primary key (id)
);
```

I would like to have a unique constraint on the
two attributes `device0id` and `device1id` such that
it does also apply with values exchanged.

For example, if there already exists a record where `device0id = '10'` and `device1id = '12'` the constraint should not only prevent insertion of a new record where the attributes have the same value but also where `device0id = '12'` and `device1id = '10'`. Is it possible? The target databases are H2 and SQL Server.

Comment: You might consider adding some code in your application (or in a trigger) that ensures that device0id is < device1id, then create a composite unique key with these two columns.

Comment: +1 to Tom's suggestion, or if you trust that only your application touches the database, you can do it there instead of in a trigger.